# Filling a 2D list with user input where value of column increases by 1 iteratively

Tags: python

I asks the user to input the values of ROW to fill a 2D list.  The value of column will be iterativley increase by 1.

```
list2D = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
user input = [1,3,0,2]  ##indexes of rows as well as values
```

i.e:

```
0th column the row = 1
1 column row = 3
2 column row = 0
3 column row = 2
```

So the new list will be:

```
newList = [[0,0,**0**,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2],[0,3,0,0]]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
list2D = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
user_input = [1,3,0,2]
for col,row in enumerate(user_input):
    list2D[row][col] = row

print(list2D)
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

or, if you do not wish to modify `list2D`:

```
import copy    
list2D = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
user_input = [1,3,0,2]
newList = copy.deepcopy(list2D)
for col,row in enumerate(user_input):
    newList[row][col] = row
```

or, using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

list2D = np.zeros((4,4))
user_input = [1,3,0,2]
list2D[user_input,range(4)] = user_input
print(list2D)
# [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  2.]
#  [ 0.  3.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: I would add that `list2D` might look better as: `list2D = [[0] * len(user_input) for i in range(len(user_input))]`

Comment: unutbu will see my suggestion, and raise me one `numpy`. Well played.